# ¿Cómo implementar AJAX en un plugin de wordpress?

Tags: php, ajax, reactjs, wordpress, web

me encuentro realizando una practica y me solicitaron implementar ajax en una parte del proyecto el cual es un reproductor de audio que esta trabajando con un plugin que la misma empresa creo, pero este cada que se actualiza la pagina se pausa y la idea es que siempre este funcionando.

Pregunte a un superior y me dijo que investigue por mi cuenta (no me brindo mas guía que esa).

Quería saber si hay alguna buena practica de como crear un plugin desde 0 ya que el que esta hecho por la empresa no esta documentado y apenas me dieron información de este mismo.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo y disculpen la molestia.

-> Poder crear un plugin para wordpress que permita tener un reproductor de audio que sea asincrónico.
-> Comprender un poco mas de como se maneja wordpress en sus archivos.

Comment: Buenas, primero que nada, acá no es lugar para preguntar esto, podrías mirar [ask] para darte una mejor idea. Segundo, lástima que en tu práctica no te esten apoyando devbidamente, pero si, debes buscar en páginas relacionadas a Wordpress y plugins Wordpress, el como hacer eso. Creo que podrías buscar en este otro sitio: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [Aquí tienes un buen punto de partida](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). Una vez hayas leído la documentación, escribe tu plugin, implementa Ajax y si tienes algún problema abre una pregunta planteando el problema, mostrando el código que falla, los errores que arroja, etc.